# AssertionError: File Not Found YOLOv5

Tags: path, yolo

[image]When I was using YOLOV5 training, run "python train.py --img 640 --batch 8 --epochs 30 --data='C:\Users\juwei\Desktop\yolov5-master\data\ road.yaml' --cfg='C:\Users\juwei\Desktop\yolov5-master\models\yolov5s.yaml' --device 0" in Terminal, an error occurred.
[image]

Comment: Hey @jiki, Please add more description to your question, what have you tried, format the error message and add your code also

Comment: download yolov5, and modify to point file path: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on windows.But the same command to train the model worked fine on google colab. For windows what I tried was to **remove all single quotes** and it worked fine for me. So your command should become as "python train.py --img 640 --batch 8 --epochs 30 --data=C:\Users\juwei\Desktop\yolov5-master\data\ road.yaml --cfg=C:\Users\juwei\Desktop\yolov5-master\models\yolov5s.yaml --device 0"

Comment: are you able to make this work with detect.py on the url that you find in https://www.wowza.com/developer/rtsp-stream-test **Which is Direct RTSP URL:** rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4